# How to Model Friendships Between IdentityUsers More Directly in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make a simple Social Network (MicroBlog) with ASP.NET Core 5+ with Entity Framework Core. I ran into a problem when modeling the friendships between the users and fetching friends of a user.

While there are a lot of guides to modeling the entity as a Many-to-Many relation, for example, [Self Referencing Many-to-Many relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728016/self-referencing-many-to-many-relations) gives a guide, link the `Relation` entity to the `Ticket` entity with two `Relation`'s collection `ICollection<Relation> RelatedTo` and `ICollection<Relation> RelatedFrom` in `Ticket`, **I'm wondering that if the relationship can be expressed more directly.**

More specifically, My `BlogUser` and `BlogUserFriendship` is defined as follow:

```
public class BlogUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BlogUser> Friends { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BlogUserFriendship> Friendships { get; set; }
}

public class BlogUserFriendship
{
    public string User1Id { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogUser User1 { get; set; }

    public string User2Id { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogUser User2 { get; set; }
}
```

I follow the instructions in [Many-to-many self referencing relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214748/many-to-many-self-referencing-relationship) to model the relations in `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<BlogUser>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Friends)
        .WithMany(u => u.Friends)
        .UsingEntity<BlogUserFriendship>(
            j => j
                .HasOne(fs => fs.User2)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(fs => fs.User2Id)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict),
            j => j
                .HasOne(fs => fs.User1)
                .WithMany(u => u.Friendships)
                .HasForeignKey(fs => fs.User1Id),
            j =>
            {
                j.HasKey(fs => new { fs.User1Id, fs.User2Id });
            }
        );
}
```

I'm wondering if **I can access one or more friends of a `BlogUser` by just accessing its `Friends` property. Or I can add another user to a user's `Friends` as simple as follow:**

```
// Inside an ASP.NET Core Controller.
// The BlogUser is a subclass of IdentityUser
var user = userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);
var friendToAdd = userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.UserId);
user.Friends.Add(friendToAdd);
await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

I tried the codes above, but it ran into a problem as follow:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an entity of type 'BlogUserFriendship' because its primary key property 'User1Id' is null.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NullableKeyIdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
......
```

**What is the problems in the codes above?**

---

What's more, I finally make it works with following codes, where `User1` is the current user (for example, let's say `UserName` is `Alice`), and `User2` is another user (let's say `UserName` is `Bob`):

```
_context.BlogUserFriendship.Add(new BlogUserFriendship
{
    User1 = user,
    User1Id = user.Id,
    User2 = friendToAdd,
    User2Id = friendToAdd.Id
});
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And the table in database succeed in showing up a friendship record, Column `User1Id` is `Alice`'s UserId, and Column `User2Id` is `Bob`'s UserId, correctly.

But when I try to fetch usernames of all friends of `Alice` as follow:

```
// Inside a Controller
[Route("Friends")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFriends()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);
    return Ok(user.Friends.Select(f => new {f.UserName}).ToList());
}
```

**The result is an empty JSON array: `[]`.** And when I put a breakpoint to debug, I saw the `Alice` user's `Friend` property is empty (Count = 0, not a null object).

I also tried to swap the `User1` and `User2` in `OnModelCreating`:

```
builder.Entity<BlogUser>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Friends)
    .WithMany(u => u.Friends)
    .UsingEntity<BlogUserFriendship>(
        j => j
            .HasOne(fs => fs.User1)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(fs => fs.User1Id)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict),
        j => j
            .HasOne(fs => fs.User2)
            .WithMany(u => u.Friendships)
            .HasForeignKey(fs => fs.User2Id),
        j =>
        {
            j.HasKey(fs => new { fs.User1Id, fs.User2Id });
        }
    );
```

Then I receive a non empty JSON array, but contains only one user, Alice, who is the one I set to `User1` when add the relationship record. **Alice's friend, Bob, was not in the array**:

```
[{"userName":"Alice"}]
```

When debugging, Alice became herself's friend, shows up in her `Friends` Collection.

I think there must be some error in my relationship model, but I can't find out what's wrong with it, or how to make it correctly.

Do you have any solutions? Or any better ideas? Thank you for your anwsering.

Comment: You can't use one and the same collection for two relationships (because many-to-many is no more or less than two one-to-many relationships). The model **must** have 2 collections. Then you can `Concat` them *in code* where needed.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for your comment. I'm new to EF so there might be some... silly mistakes in my codes. `Concat` will work well if there are 2 collections in model, and I think it can be queried easily. I just want to find out that if there is a way to make the process of creating a relationship more simple, like adding a user to friends list by `user.Friends.Add(anotherUser)`. Is there a solution in EF? Again, really appreciate your help. :-)

Comment: No, there isn't. I guess that's because of the relational db model. Or even just logically, if you have just one collection, when you add object to it, how it will know who is `User1` and who - `User2` in the linking table? And how to perform the navigation fixup, i.e. imagine `User u1, u2;`, and then `u1.Friends.Add(u2)` should automatically do `u2.Friends.Add(u1)`, right? But that's still 1 link entry, and again it's unclear who is who there.

Comment: @IvanStoev I got that. Thank you very much!